# Command pipeline run out of Perl fails at sed prepending a path

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I am writing a Perl program which needs to call bash scripts to search, sort, and insert a path in the front of each line. Below is my script.

```
...
system("grep $a $file | grep $b | sort -uk 5,6 | sort -k 2 | sed 's/^/$dir /'");
...
```

where `$a`, `$b`, `$file`, and `$dir` are variables. Among them,

```
$dir = "/home/user/simulations/dir1/dir2/dir3/.../dirn/$file"
```

If I use a string without `/`, I can run this script without any problems. However, if I use a variable `$dir` in which the value consists of `/`, I always get the error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
```

Because the length/scale of each directory is different, is there an easy way to avoid inserting `\`? Any suggestion and help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is very surprising that perl `needs to call BASH scripts to search, sort and insert a path in the front of each line`. You'd think such a huge language with all those libraries would be able to do the job itself without calling a bunch of external tools to do it. Assuming you're right though, why not get your script working outside of perl and THEN try to include it in the perl script once you've worked out the kinks like this one. There are hundreds of scripts in this forum (posted almost daily!) that will show you how to address that specific problem.

Comment: Honestly, I just use PERL for a short while. Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in my first comment? If so, what were the results of searching the forum and trying to get it working outside of perl?

Comment: Yes. I did it. I cannot avoid inserting "\" in the front of "/". I do not know whether I have an easier way.

Comment: Yes you can avoid it, just use a different delimiter. Honestly there's been multiple sed questions this week alone about this. Just look for sed questions that mention delimiters or look at the sed man page.

Comment: @Ed Morton, Switching delimiters just shifts the problem instead of fixing it. Using `\Q$dir\E` is the real fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this runs out of a Perl script there is no good reason to go for external tools for any of the processing.  Perl has varied support for this kind of work and excels at it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(uniq);

my $file = shift @ARGV;
die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if not $file or not -f $file;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my $patt1 = qr/./;  # match any one character; for testing
my $patt2 = qr/./;  # these are "$a" and "$b"

# Only lines with both patterns
my @lines = grep { /$patt1/ and /$patt2/ } <$fh>;

my $dir = '/some/path/';
my %freq;

my @sorted =
    map { "$dir " . join ' ', @$_ }
    grep { ++$freq{join("", @{$_}[4,5])} == 1 } 
    sort { 
        $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] or
        $a->[4] cmp $b->[4] or
        $a->[5] cmp $b->[5]
    }   
    map { [ split ] } 
    @lines;

say for @sorted;
```

I use `$patt1` and `$patt2` instead of `$a` and `$b`, which are special names that shouldn't be used (and are very bad variable names).  I set them to match any one character, for my tests.

In the sorting statement, an arrayref is first made of words for each line (fields for external `sort`). Then these arrayrefs are sorted by the second field and then by 5th and 6th. The sorted set is then filtered so to keep only the first line from each subset of lines with equal 5th and 6th field (unique in these sorted fields, `-uk 5,6` in external`sort`).

Finally the lines are reconstituted as strings and prepended a `$dir`.

This has been tested with a file I made up but as I am not certain what exactly your pipeline is meant to do it may need changes to match that purpose.

The script takes all lines from a file and retains all those which have patterns.  The memory usage is then multiple times that, due to the `sort` statement, and for files of extreme size this may be too much. 
In such a case we'd have an example when an external tool is helpful, since system `sort` does not load whole files in memory when they are too large.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am writing a scripts which scan my research data. The column number of my data is various. Furthermore, my data is more than 1 million records.  I do not know your way is more efficient than BASH scripts. Any further suggestion and help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Leon  Very glad to help. With files of that size this should still work.  The efficiency of most code can always be improved, but is it needed? Does this run too slow or does it take too much memory?  Test, and let me know if there is a problem.  I don't know what bash script you have in mind and how it compares to that.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do all the operations in Perl (without calling system commands `sort`, `grep`, and `sed`):

First read the file line by line and construct the sorting keys for each line:

```
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    # IMPORTANT: $a and $b are special names in Perl, so avoid these.
    #   I used here $aa and $bb...
    if ($line =~ /\Q$aa\E/ && $line =~ /\Q$bb\E/) { # grep $a $file | grep $b
        my @fields = split " ", $line;
        my $key1 = join "", @fields[4..5];
        my $key2 = $fields[1];
        push @lines, [$key1, $key2, $line];
    }
}
```

Now, as you have the `@lines` array, you can simply do:

```
my %seen;
say for map { "$dir " . $_->[2] }
  sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } 
  grep { !$seen{ $_->[2] }++ }
  sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @lines;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am writing a scripts which scan my research data. The column number of my data is various. Furthermore, my data is more than 1 million records. I do not know your way is more efficient than BASH scripts. Any further suggestion and help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You are improperly generating the `sed` program (as seen by printing `"sed 's/^/$dir /'"`).

You are also improperly generating the shell command.

Fixed:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = join(' | ',
   shell_quote('grep', '--', $pattern1, $file),
   shell_quote('grep', '--', $pattern2),
   'sort -uk 5,6',
   'sort -k 2',
   shell_quote('sed', "s/^/\Q$dir\E /"),
);

system($cmd);
```

Note that I replaced `$a` and `$b` with `$pattern1` and `$pattern2`. `$a` and `$b` are special variables, and `$a and`$b` are meaningless names.